# How can I prove that an different compactification to the Stone-Cech compactification doen't have it universal property?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, universal-property, compactification

Let $S(X)=\prod_{U \in \tau_{X}} \{ 0,1 \}_{U} $ with $(X,\tau_{X})$ $T_0$ topological space and $\{ 0,1 \}$  the Sierpinski's space. Cosiderer the map $e$ from $X$ to $S(X)$. $e:X\rightarrow S(X)$ such that $e(x)_{U}=0$  if  $x \in U$ and $e(x)_{U}=1$ if not. I've proved that $X \simeq e[X]$. Since $S(X)$ is compact hausdorff space, then $\beta_{2}(X)= \overline{e[X]}$ is a compactification for $X$. My question is:

How can I prove that $\beta_{2}(X)$  doesn't have the universal property?

I mean this property:

Given any continuous map
$f:X\rightarrow C$ of $X$ into a compact Hausdorff space $C$, the map $f$ extends uniquely to a
continuous map $g:\beta(X)\rightarrow C)$ .

$X$ is $T_{0}$ only.

I have this idea:
 to prove:
 For any $f$ real-valued function on $X$,$f :X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we'll have the map $f$ don't extends uniquelyto a continuous map $g :\beta_{2}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Help!

Comment: $S(X)$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @EricWofsey But $\beta_2[X]$ could be Hausdorff.

Comment: Anything with this universal property is unique. So you can prove this by showing that $\beta_2(X)$ is not homeomorphic to the Stone–Čech compactification.

Comment: The universal property for $(\beta X, \beta:X \to \beta X)$ is: for all continuous $f: X \to [0,1]$ there is a unique $\beta f: \beta X \to [0,1]$ such that $\beta f \circ \beta = f$. Not to $\Bbb R$(!) and the connecting map $\beta$ is involved(!) Don't assume $X \subseteq \beta X$.